# Running functions serially and parallel

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've 3 functions : **func1**, **func2** and **func3**.

**func1** and **func2** use `load()` to fetch content dynamically.

**func3** runs on content loaded by **func2** and shows an animation on it.

I want **func1** and **func2** to run parallel (for better performance) and then I want **func3** to run once the previous two are done.

```
    var funcList = ['func1','func2'];
    $.each(funcList, function(i,v){
            window[v]();
    })
    func3();
```

I notice that the animation of **func3()** doesn't run probably because the content of **func2** wasnt fetched yet. I ran **func3()** from the console once the page was loaded and the animation ran fine. Why is this happening? Isn't `each()` synchronous ?

Comment: Yes, `jQuery.each()` **is** synchronous, but your two functions aren't. It will execute both functions, then execute `func3()`, but since the other two have AJAX calls in them the callbacks aren't guaranteed to have been executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is because `$.ajax` is asynchronous.. by the time `func3` is called , there is no guarantee that the other two ajax call have been completed successfully..you can use [$.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to check the returned promise and once the two function is resolved run the third function.

try this

```
$.when(funcList).then(func3)
```

example

```
var func1=function(){
  return $.get('url',function(data){....});
}

var func2=function(){
  return $.get('url2',function(data){....});
}

function func3(){
  // animation here
}

$.when(func1(),func2()).then(func3)
```

Comment: Will `$.when(func1(),func2())` ensure that 1 and 2 are run in parallel ?

Comment: yes .. it runs in parallel... $.when provides a way to execute callback functions based on one or more objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous events... so if the functions in when execute successfully the goes to `then` ..

Comment: Hey, I couldnt get your method to work. I have made a simple fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Y4PHM/1/ Could you please look into it and get it to work ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/Y4PHM/3/ here you go... but this is just append so you won't notice the difference.. if u have ajax,post,get (asynchornus) in function then you will notice.....

Comment: Oh sorry for the embarrassing typo. I got it to work. Thanks :)